# Why doesn't describe_table return matching tables if full name specified?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, boto3

I'm learning DynamoDB and find myself wanting a script to check to see if a particular table exists before it proceeds with anything else. I'm using Python and the boto3 module.

I already have a table called 'cartracker'. If I:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
client.list_tables(ExclusiveStartTableName='cartracker')
```

The result is this ('TableNames' is empty):

```
{'TableNames': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'MEKJ80167PEHUABC8DDVS70B4VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'x-amz-crc32': '1315925753', 'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Tue, 31 Oct 2017 17:49:08 GMT', 'content-length': '17', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'MEKJ80167PEHUABC8DDVS70B4VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}}
```

If I pass a partial string however (notice the lack of an 'r' in 'cartracke'):

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
client.list_tables(ExclusiveStartTableName='cartracke')
```

Then I get what I expected ('TableNames' is populated):

```
{'TableNames': ['cartracker'], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'FN7JH1JNFC1RNJHVFD15CM23KJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'x-amz-crc32': '505128313', 'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Tue, 31 Oct 2017 17:49:12 GMT', 'content-length': '29', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'FN7JH1JNFC1RNJHVFD15CM23KJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}}
```

I have no idea why it would want to behave this way and it feels buggy. I can't see anything in the documentation suggesting that this is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only use the *ExclusiveStartTableName* parameter if you had previously called list_tables() and it returned an indication (in *LastEvaluatedTableName*) that more results were available. This is the general pattern that AWS SDKs use for pagination, when there are more results than can reasonably be returned in a single API invocation. Typically you would initially call list_tables() with no parameters.

In your case, however, simply call [describe_table()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.describe_table) for the specific table of interest. Or you could call list_tables() with zero parameters, but that would potentially return other tables too.

Comment: I see now, thanks. I didn't consider that describe_table() returned anything without arguments.  I moved to using: 

`tablelist = client.list_tables()['TableNames']

if 'cartracker' in tablelist:
# do stuff`

Comment: You've missed the point. No, describe_table() doesn't return *anything* if you call it with zero parameters (it will actually fail with ParamValidationError because TableName is required). You should instead call describe_table(TableName='cartracker'). If it succeeds then you know that you have a table named cartracker. If it throws ResourceNotFoundException then you know you don't have such a table.